# dynamic borders for columns

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this script that sets borders for range if first cell is not empty

```
function borders() {

   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var sheetmon = ss.getActiveSheet()
  var rows = sheetmon.getRange('A55:AY177'); 
  var numRows = rows.getNumRows(); 
  var values = rows.getValues(); 
  var testvalues = sheetmon.getRange('A55:A177')

  rows.setBorder(false, false, false, false, false, false, "black", SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_MEDIUM); 

  for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
      var n = i + 55;
      Logger.log(testvalues[i] > 0);
      if (testvalues[i] == '') { 
      } else {
        Logger.log(testvalues[i]);
        sheetmon.getRange('A' + n + ':AY' + n).setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true, "gray", SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID); 
     }
  }}
```

Question - how to set dynamic final column for setBorder? Instead of column AY I want to set the one where the last cell in row 53 is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

Use `getRange()`, but [using numeric values](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow-column-numrows-numcolumns) rather than A1 notation.

```
sheetmon.getRange(n, 1, 1, numberOfColumnsInThisRow).setBorder(...
```